# User cannot mount disks after upgrade to Saucy

Tags: upgrade, mount, kubuntu, 13.10

I upgraded to Saucy and I am not able to mount any disks any more, because I am not permitted:

[image]

I am able to mount the disk with `mount`, but that is not really a solution...

How can I enable mounting for the user again?

`blkid`

```
/dev/sda5: UUID="fd5c349d-683e-4958-9fd2-bd825f10b471" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="4e0ae3da-4001-43c7-99b4-95112b9177fd" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="MU-3-466G-info" UUID="6c680a34-5392-4cff-8f9a-ac9c906db75f" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc2: UUID="764d42e6-66af-413c-9148-2709c8b084c1" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
```

`fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0719ee6e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda2            2046   593893375   296945665    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5            2048   554829823   277413888   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 30.0 GB, 30016659456 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3649 cylinders, total 58626288 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e8129

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048    58626047    29312000   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 500.1 GB, 500107859968 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773164 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0007fa35

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              63      208844      104391   83  Linux
/dev/sdc2          208845   976768064   488279610   83  Linux
```

`cat /etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=4e0ae3da-4001-43c7-99b4-95112b9177fd /               ext4    discard,errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=fd5c349d-683e-4958-9fd2-bd825f10b471 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /tmp was on /dev/sda7 during installation
#UUID=c0e28121-6b95-459a-8f88-3e9ee11292aa /tmp            ext4    defaults        0       2
# /var was on /dev/sda6 during installation
#UUID=9eaadf4b-95ef-40d3-860f-48e6f4ea9186 /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=e2a27ad7-d887-4fe7-831f-bbde2e4e3056 none            swap    sw              0       0

#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: edit your question and post the output of these commands: `sudo blkid`, `sudo fdisk -l` and `cat /etc/fstab` Reply..

Comment: @SauravKumar Added the output.

Comment: How many HDD have you connected to your system.. :P It is above to my imagination, I'm not able to figure out some file system like `crypto_LUKS` which is one of your file system of your 500 GB HDD. So you want to access the all 2 partitions of 500 GB? I don't know exactly whether it will work but you can edit `/etc/fstab` file to mount your partitions automatically when your system starts..

Comment: `sda` is my HDD for data within the laptop. `sdb` is the system SSD, also built in. `sdc` is a USB drive with two partitions on it. I want to mount both. One has some information on it, the second is encrypted and has all my user data on it.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever DM you use (kdm, gdm, lightdm, etc.), do the following:

1. Append the following to the top of the `/etc/pam.d/your_dm_file`:

   ```
   session required pam_loginuid.so
   session required pam_systemd.so
   ```
2. Logout, Restart X, Login
3. Check that everything works
4. Remove fix you applied in step 1.
5. Logout, Restart X, Login
6. Check that everything STILL works!

This so-called fix (step 1) can be removed once you login and check that you have a working system. It apparently allows the upgraded system to complete some process that fixes the underlying problem. Once done (after an admin login?), the fix can be removed.

It also cleared up all the crash reports I was getting directly after login.