# Cannot shut down from KDE workspace after upgrade to Saucy

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, 13.10, shutdown

Adding to my sequel of things broken after the upgrade:

- [NetworkManager broken after upgrade to Kubuntu Saucy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363945/networkmanager-broken-after-upgrade-to-kubuntu-saucy)
- [User cannot mount disks after upgrade to Saucy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365171/user-cannot-mount-disks-after-upgrade-to-saucy)

When I select shutdown from the KDE workspace, I only get back to the login screen. When I do `sudo poweroff`, I can halt the machine.

I have the impression that something is fundamentally broken with permissons on my system. Networking only works from a root shell, mounting as well and now shutdown.

What is up with all that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My system was presenting exactly the same symptoms after the upgrade to saucy baulked halfway through at tex-common and some other packages, leaving me with a crippled laptop. Via chroot I reconfigured the policy packages as explained in your other thread
`dpkg-reconfigure policykit-1 policykit-desktop-privileges consolekit polkit-kde-1`. I also finished off the upgrade with `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`.

That probably helped, but still didn't give me a working network connection. What finally worked for me was `pam-auth-update --force` as explained [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1185592). So it looks like it was something "fundamentally broken with permissions".

Comment: Thanks for the insights on the cause of this trouble. I have a lot of tex packages installed, that might be similar. I have a fresh reinstall now, so I cannot say if your approach would have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This helped. Thank you. However, the commands really didn't do anything. Added the following line in /etc/pam.d/common-session and then sound, wifi & shutdown/reboot all works just fine:

```
session optional        pam_systemd.so
```

Comment: Wait a minute. What is `systemd` doing in Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu now has a stripped down version of systemd. IIRC, they split out logind from systemd. So, some parts of systemd is actually available in ubuntu. At least loginctl, hostnamectl etc. works on ubuntu.